# tmux resizep not working as expected if run in shell command

Tags: bash, scripting, resize, tmux

I'm triyng to setup a tmux session from a bash script, without using any session manager like tmuxinator/tmuxp/...

If I run this code

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux \
    new '/path/to/a/script.sh' \; \
    splitw -v '/path/to/another/program' \; \
    selectp -U \; \
    resizep -y 4 \;
```

it works, except for one thing: according to `man tmux` I expect it to resize the top pane to 4 lines but it resizes it to a variable number of lines that depends on the size of the terminal window (it is not necessarily 4 lines and it is not 4% of the window height).

If I remove the resizep line

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux \
    new '/path/to/a/script.sh' \; \
    splitw -v '/path/to/another/program' \; \
    selectp -U \;
```

and then from inside the session I manually run the `:resizep -y 4` tmux command, then it resizes it effectively to 4 lines.

Does anybody know why it happens and what can I do to fix it?

According to `man tmux`

**Specs** 
OS: Arch Linux 
WM: dwm (suckless) 
Terminal: ts (suckless) 
Shell: bash

EDIT: I execute this bash script in a ts/bash shell, so at the moment I execute it, the shell window already exists with its width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!
Finally I solved it (after almost an year) and it was so simple...

I just added a name for the session and specified the session name and window number in the resizep command.

I paste here the code, so maybe it will help someone in the future.

```
tmux \
    new '/path/to/a/script.sh' \; \
    rename "session_name" \; \
    splitw -v '/path/to/another/script.sh' \; \
    selectp -U \; \
    resizep -t "session_name:1" -y 4 \;
```

Notice the `1` in the session name. Normally it would be `0` but in my .tmuxrc I have set `set -g base-index 1`